# How can I Drag and Drop with jsp/html/js/java

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, drag-and-drop

I am trying to add two separate features together that I have working I have working separately (drag and drop feature as well as my upload files to a file system). Ultimately I would like to be able to drag and drop files and then upon "submission" I will then upload those said files to y file system. I have my html setup to drag and drop fine and I also have my java pulling the data fine and storing it in the file system.

My mind is kinda out of it trying to get my "input" code to grab the data that was dragged and dropped. I'm fairly new to front end development FYI. How can I grab the drag and dropped data and send it back to the "input"?

```
        <table class="table table-bordered ">
        <tr> <td colspan="2" class="tdheader2"> <b>Testing upload</b> </td> </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><B>Testing Stuff</b></td>
            <td>
            <div >Drag & Drop Files Here</div>

                <form id="dragandrophandler" method="post" action="/CSRapp/dragDropUpload.do" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    Upload testing: 
                    <input type="file" name="dragDropUpload" id ="testUpload" multiple= "" value= ""/> 
                    <br/><br/> 
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>                           
                </form>
            </td>
            <script>
            var obj = $("#dragandrophandler");
            obj.on('dragenter', function (e) 
            {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).css('border', '2px solid #0B85A1');
            });
            obj.on('dragover', function (e) 
            {
                 e.stopPropagation();
                 e.preventDefault();
            });
            obj.on('drop', function (e) 
            {                
                 $(this).css('border', '2px dotted #0B85A1');
                 e.preventDefault();
                 //idk how I would send this back to the input
            }); 
            </script>

        </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Still haven't figure this out :/

Comment: ... any suggestions???

Comment: Still no help...